# Retrieving model attributes in Strapi from model lifecycle methods

Tags: strapi

Inside my models directory (models belongs to /api/post), there are `Post.js` and `Post.settings.json`. I created an attribute `title` in `Post.settings.json`, and in `Post.js` I have:

```
beforeCreate: async (model, attrs, options) => {
  console.log(model.attributes.title);
};
```

I don't have any idea why it gives me an error `error TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`. Does anyone know? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use mongoose, then this callback return only one parameter so if you would read tittle you should read reference from first parameter.

```
beforeCreate: async (model) => {
  console.log(model.title);
};
```

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/models.html#lifecycle-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You will access to your **title** with `attrs.title`

Comment: Hi @Jim LAURIE, I tried both ways `console.log(model.attrs.title)` and `console.log(attrs.title)` but still not working. :(

Comment: If you use mongoose, then this callback return only one parameter so if you would read tittle you should read reference from first parameter.